# Is there any way to block all downloads from Chrome?

Tags: downloads, browser

I need to block anyone using this PC from downloading anything from the internet using Chrome. Is there any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable downloads in Chrome.

However, you could set up a proxy server and / or [use parental controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls) on your computer to limit access to certain resources.

Comment: Could he direct downloads to /dev/null and make the conf file immutable?